# Deriving Non-linear acoustic wave models, equilibrium state assumption

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, equilibrium, non-linear-systems

The standard derivation in obtaining a single wave equation involves making use of the heat equation with a Taylor expansion of the equation of state, then differentiating this equation and the continuity equation with respect to time, and combining with the divergence of the NS equation.

From the literature I have found, it tends to be assumed an equilibrium state of:

1. $u_0=0$ (vanishing equilibrium velocity)
2. $\partial_t \rho_0 =0$(no time dependence on the equilibrium density)

(which together, by the continuity => vanishing spatial dependence on the equilibrium velocity as well).

Probably a stupid question but, if assuming a non-vanishing equilibrium velocity, (and of course under the same assumptions corresponding to used to derive the specific model), do we expect to obtain the same wave equation as we would if vanishing equilibrium velocity was assumed?

Many thanks

Comment: "involves making use of the heat equation" I don't think so. The heat, or energy equation is just removed by using an isothermal sound speed. For the rest of your question: It's really easy to do this, go have a try...

Answer (score 0):

No, you would not get the same equation.  The same is true for the linear wave equation; if you account for moving media (with the exception of uniformly moving media, which is just a coordinate transformation) you get a significantly more complicated equation than the wave equation.  Including nonlinearity just makes everything a lot more complicated.

What you can say is that the resulting equation will be the original nonlinear wave equation with additional terms that account for the moving media.  We can say this because everything we are doing is a perturbation, and we can incorporate higher-order terms as a series, hence the inclusion of additional terms.

I hope this is helpful!